# $(this).data('yiiActiveForm').attributes is undefined in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

> $(this).data('yiiActiveForm').attributes is undefined in yii2 advance
>   template

Form is like bellow

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'form-user-password']); ?>
<?= $form->field($model,'current_password')->passwordInput('id'=>'test') ?>
<?= $form->field($model,'password_new')->passwordInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model,'confirm_password')->passwordInput() ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Update' ,['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

This is my ajax request.I just need update the attribute if ajax response return  validation error.

```
function formuserpassword(e) {


        var requestUrl = "http://localhost/36writers/frontend/web/site/change-password";

        var funcBeforeSend = function (data) {

                        };

        var funcSuccess = function (data) {  
    if(data.status === 'success') {

    }
    if(data.status === 'failure') {
        $('#form-user-password').yiiActiveForm('updateAttribute','test',['message']);
    }

        };

        var funcError = function (err) {
            if (err.status != 302) {
                alert('Error!' + JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        };

        jQuery.ajax({
            'url': requestUrl,
            'data': $(this).serialize(),
            'type': 'post',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'beforeSend': funcBeforeSend,
            'success': funcSuccess,
            'error': funcError,
            'cache': false
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Please explain better what are you doing and when and  where this happen.

Comment: This happen when i am trying to update model by ajax.Please check updated code

Comment: I don't understand the first row  $('#........   ) .....what's mean?

Comment: You are calling a yii2 function inside javascript?

Comment: $(this).data('yiiActiveForm').attributes this is not a php function.this is a javascript which is yii.activeForm.js

Comment: show it please. the call you do for ajax is not correct

Comment: What do you need to see ?and what is wrong with ajax ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90690/discussion-between-diga88-and-scaisedge).

Comment: In this moment i can't i'm going out

Comment: I found the solution.I should use 'enableAjaxValidation' => true .